# Grant remote access for MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I am new to all this.  Installed MariaDB and HeidiSQL on Windows server B and all running fine.  I need to grant access for Windows server A to access the database with HeidiSQL.  I ran this query.
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'A' IDENTIFIED BY 'root_pw_on_B' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

From server A I still get "Host A not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server" when setting up a session in HeidiSQL.

Both servers are on-prem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So couple of things, you are trying to grant root access from anywhere. That is a highly insecure practice. `'root'@'A'` should not be okay. Instead create another super user, allow all access and then try to connect using that user.

1. `CREATE USER 'sammy'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
2. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '<user>'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
3. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

This should do the trick.

Comment: Bingo!  Yes, I knew that was bound to be bad practice, but was just trying to get something going.  Let me ask the next question since I am not even sure what to search for (and having trouble even formatting this reply!).  SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;  still shows root and the host I was trying to grant.  How do I clean that up?

Comment: You want to delete the `root` user? and please do accept the answer. Glad i could help.

Comment: I assume I don't want to delete the root user completely?  In this list I would remove root, amsalpha.  (Can't paste the image.)